# @grails.project.name@' is missing required source folder: 'grails-app/controllers'

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Grails got installed and the project got loaded too. But while running, the following error is shown:

```
'@grails.project.name@' is missing required source folder: 'grails-app/controllers'
```

I am using STS IDE.

Comment: Is the project one you created, or one you obtained from elsewhere?

Comment: add the directory structure for your grails project to the question, perhaps?  also, can you run from command line?

Comment: @ertune project is working fine on my development system but when client imported the same project it gives error as mentioned above.